# Will not receive 1095-A for federal taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, healthcare, new-jersey

I bought a health care plan on a state exchange but do not receive a subsidy and so did not receive a 1095-A form. However, on my federal income taxes, it is asking "Did you have health insurance from the Federal Health Insurance Marketplace (healthcare.gov) or a state-based exchange (Form 1095-A)?" and when I say yes, it requires submission of data from the 1095-A form, and says that if I don't provide it, the IRS might automatically reject the return.

I could submit "no" for the question about having a marketplace plan, presuming they mean did you get a subsidy for such a plan, but it isn't literally true.

Edit: I reached out to the customer support of my state (New Jersey) exchange and they said categorically that no one without a subsidy gets a 1095-A in my state.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I bought a health care plan on a state exchange but do not receive a subsidy and so did not receive a 1095-A form

You should have received the form 1095-A regardless of whether you received a subsidy or not.

See the [instructions to the form 1095-A](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1095a#en_US_2022_publink1000306237):

> Health Insurance Marketplaces must file Form 1095-A to report information on **all enrollments** in qualified health plans in the individual market through the Marketplace

Reach out to the marketplace operator and ask them to provide it to you.

Comment: I reached out to their customer support and the representative said adamantly that forms are only sent to people with subsidies. What should I do now?

Comment: These are usually state-run. Which State is that? Call your representative.

Comment: The state is NJ, the representative of the NJ exchange I spoke to said they didn't send 1095-A forms to people who don't receive subsidies

Comment: @ak0000 your representative in State legislature.

Comment: Got it, interesting, thanks